# Moving down and keeping all enlarged axis number labellings of a plot in r

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I have a plot with a logarithmic scale:

```
png("test.png")
set.seed(20)
x = 1:100
y = sample(100)
plot(x,y,log="x",xaxt='n',cex.axis=2)
axis(1,cex.axis=4)
dev.off()
```

`test.png` yields:

[image]

I want 2 things,

1. Move the axis numbers down so that they don't overlap the axis and it's ticks
2. Keep the disappeared numbers "2", "10", "50" even if they overlap with the other numbers.
   (The axis numbers should not reduce in size!)

Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my solution. Hope it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? We can use `mapply()` which calls `axis()` once for each tick location returned by `axTicks()`. Doing this allows you to keep the missing values that are not shows to avoid over plotting. Also, I threw in some padding with `padj` so your values aren't entering into the plot itself.

```r
png("test.png")
set.seed(20)
x = 1:100
y = sample(100)


plot(x,y,log="x",xaxt='n',cex.axis=2)
mapply(axis, 
       side = 1, 
       at = axTicks(1), 
       labels = axTicks(1), 
       cex.lab=4, 
       cex.axis=4, 
       cex.main=4, 
       cex.sub=4, 
       padj = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: The axis number should not reduce in size. I've pointed that out now in my post.

Comment: @AlexLee - I have updated my answer. Please upvote and then accept by clicking the checkmark if it is acceptable. Thank you!